# TFS 2015 Agile: limit permissions to change states or move sprints

Tags: tfs-2015

Is there a way to set user permissions to restrict changing states (status) or moving items from one sprint (iteration) to another in Microsoft TFS 2015?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Changing the state of the work item" and "Moving the work item to a different iteration" are both examples of a more generic permission - Edit Work Item. It is defined on [area level in TFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx). For a specific area path you can deny "Edit work items in this node" permission, and the user won't be able to

- Change the state of work items in this area
- Move the work items in this area to a different iteration
- Modify the work items in any other way

First two points is what you aim for. The last is probably not. If you need to granular permissions on a field level, I am almost sure it is not possible.